# Paging list gmail with .Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail, gmail-api

Gmail Api Users.messages: list return a response

```
{
  "messages": [
    users.messages Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

I use ***nextPageToken*** to go to next page list gmail but i don't how to return previous page.

My code implement get gmail list use Gmail Api.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(HttpRequestMessage request, string labels = null, string nextPage = null)
{
    GetCredential();
    return CreateHttpResponse(request, async () =>
    {
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
            ApplicationName = "Mail box",
        });

        var messages = new List<Message>();
        var emailMessages = new List<EmailMessageViewModel>();

        var listRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
        if (labels != null) listRequest.LabelIds = labels.ToUpper();
        listRequest.MaxResults = 20;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPage))
        {
            listRequest.PageToken = nextPage;
        }

        var listMessagesResponse = listRequest.Execute();
        messages.AddRange(listMessagesResponse.Messages);

        for (var i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
        {
            var message = messages[i];
            var getRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", message.Id);
            getRequest.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
            getRequest.MetadataHeaders = new Repeatable<string>(new[] {"Subject", "Date", "From"});

            messages[i] = getRequest.Execute();
            var unread = false;
            foreach (var label in messages[i].LabelIds.Where(label => label.Equals("UNREAD")))
            {
                unread = true;
            }
            emailMessages.Add(new EmailMessageViewModel()
            {
                Id = messages[i].Id,
                Snippet = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(messages[i].Snippet),
                UnRead = unread,
                SizeEstimate = $"{messages[i].SizeEstimate:n0}",
                From = messages[i].Payload.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "From")?.Value,
                Subject = messages[i].Payload.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Subject")?.Value,
                Date = messages[i].InternalDate.ToString()
            });
        }

        var emails = new ListEmailViewModel
        {
            NextPageToken = listMessagesResponse.NextPageToken,
            Emails = emailMessages
        };

        var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, emails);
        return await Task.Run(() => response);
    });
}
```

Comment: As you start your requests from the first page, keep the tokens in a list in your code so that you can move back and forth between the different pages (with no token at all for the first page)...